# Wierd font in Javascript alert Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fonts, alert

We have a plain text message being output in a javascript alert() popup for form errors on our system. For some reason Google Chrome is displaying part of it in a weird font, as seen in the image below.

[image: Image of Weird Font]

Does anyone know why?

The plain text is:

```
"___________________________________________________________________

The form was not submitted because of the following error(s).
Please correct these error(s) and re-submit the form.
___________________________________________________________________

- The following required field(s) are empty:
    Title
    Company
"
```

Comment: Could you maybe attach the image?

Comment: I did try but i don't have the required reputation unfortunately (which is terrible!) Any suggestions?

Comment: Update the image to imgur and share the link :)

Comment: Great... edited. Thanks

Comment: And edited to make the image visible (Restricting new users from spamming images all over the place has a reason - its far from "terrible"!)

Comment: Have you tried just editing the alert text? Chrome maybe doing something fancy with your text. Trying changing this `The following required field(s) are empty
    Title
    Company` Remove the : and -

Comment: Could you also share the string that you send to alert?

Comment: But hey, don't worry too much about it. Alerts aren't meant to be styled. If you want funky messages, use overlays of some sort (there are tons of libraries that can help you out here, ie. bootstrap or jquery ui)

Comment: Why are you using alerts in 2015?

Comment: Salaman, We are talking about a very old system, coded mainly in Classic ASP and using YUI functionality for dropdowns and popups. Slowly migrating to .NET and using our own popups but as we're a small team it's taking a while unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome appears to do this on certain OS's when a line is preceded by a tab (`\t`)

[image]

```js
alert("Normal text\r\n\tPreceeded by a tab");
```

Which is supersonically bizarre behaviour - no other browser does that.

At least its not a [6 year old bug](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bfmvqAvtSd4) oh.wait.fail!

Comment: Was just debugging following feedback above and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Not on mac-os, then it's hypersonically bizarre behaviour (some would say a bug?)

Comment: Seems to be OS-specific as well. In ubuntu it just shows as normal text prepended with a space...